# Exporting via Phpmyadmin Charset

Tags: restore, mysql-5.7, export, character-set

MySQL 5.7

I am exporting my db from my web host using phpmyadmin. This produces a single .sql file.

When I check the export with Notepad+, there are special characters in the file.

e.g. in my source db the following text;

> The cost is £40 per person.

Is changed in the sql file to;

> The cost is Ã‚Â£40 per person.

The charset on the source db are all either **utft** or **utf8mb4**

DO I need to change any specific setting on the source db to ensure that there are no special characters during export? Currently I am leaving all the phpmyadmin settings default.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [--hex-blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) when you run the mysqldump

Since you are using phpmyadmin, look around in the Advanced tab to see if there is a HEX Blob Option. The mysqldump should also have directives present to preserve the intended character set info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not using mysqldump, I am logged into my we host's control panel and opening phpmyadmin. In the export tab I can't see anything related to hex-blob, only the standard export options e.g. charset (which is set to utf-8), compression, add statements etc.